# What is the function to run simulation in MEL?

Tags: scripting, simulation, maya, mel

I would like to create a MEL script that creates a scene, setting up ncloth and passive collider objects and run the simulation up to a certain frame.

In the script editor, I can see the scene set-up but there is no function starting the simulation.

Comment: Can you make the question more clearer? What do you mean by you can see the scene setup in the script editor? Do you have any code written so far?

Comment: I followed the nCloth tutorial on http://docs.autodesk.com/MAYAUL/2015/ENU/GettingStarted/#!/url=./files/Creating_nCloth_collisions_Introduction.htm
This requires to click on the "play" button to begin the simulation but in the script history, I didn't see any MEL command doing this. That's why I wonder if there is a MEL command that starts/stops the simulation ? I hope this is clearer now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The technique that @Andreas suggests is sometimes called "command harvesting". It is a great way to learn what and how Maya is doing things. But to answer your specific question:

You can use `cmds.play()` to start playing back on Maya. [See the docs for options](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/CommandsPython/play.html).

You might want to set the start frame and end frame of the playback range using the `cmds.playbackOptions()` command. [See the docs for options](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/CommandsPython/playbackOptions.html).

So you would do: (relevant explanatory comments added)

```
# egs. to play from frame 1 to 120
# also note that the playbackSpeed flag is used
# we need to set this to 0 to "play every frame".
# setting maxPlaybackSpeed to 0 will result in free playback, so the playback isn't clamped.
# At this point, playback wouldn't be realtime, but it will be accurate.
# Dynamics and simulations must be played back like this or the nucleus will not evaluate properly.

cmds.playbackOptions(animationStartTime=1, animationEndTime=120, playbackSpeed=0, maxPlaybackSpeed=0)

# now start playback
cmds.play(forward=True)
```

EDIT: I just noticed that you had asked for MEL commands. Just take the above commands and MEL-ify them, like so:

```
playbackOptions -e animationStartTime 1 animationEndTime 120 playbackSpeed 0;
play -f 1;
```

Suggestion: It is best to playblast this playback to watch it in proper fps and playback speed.

Hope that was useful.

Comment: Thanks very much for the detailed answer. I have followed your step and add the exporting at the end but it seems that the exporting is called BEFORE the simulation finishes. The script works fine otherwise if it is launched within Maya (i.e. from script editor).

Comment: I have debugged my code using pdb and found that the exporting is called AFTER the simulation. So I don't think cmds.evalDeferred() would solve the problem. Magically, there is no problem when the same script is launched within Maya. Here is my full code http://codepaste.net/tfvs68 that is using the dataset from the "getting started in Maya" : http://docs.autodesk.com/MAYAUL/2015/ENU/GettingStarted/#!/url=./files/Scripting_in_Maya_Introduction.htm . Could you please take a quick look at the code and tell me if there is some evident error ?

Comment: Can you try executing the file command using the cmds.file()? eval is usually evil.

Comment: Also if your purpose is to export the mesh after simulation, try using @theodox answer - use bakeSimulation

Comment: Eval is not eevil in maya. If it was then you'd be in trouble as half of the entire GUI is calling eval. Maya is inherently not safe.

Comment: Right. I just prefer avoiding using eval, esp the mel.eval one, when I am writing in Python, unless the command doesn't exist in Python. If I have to use eval, I prefer using PyMel's as it is traceable.

Comment: bakeSimulation does not change much ... I always have the impression that the simulation is not run when the script is launched in standalone mode since it's running very quickly. Maybe some plugins need to be loaded in order for the simulation to run ?

Answer (score 1):

In the Script Editor you can tell Maya to "Echo all commands". If you enable that, then do something in the UI, it will output all the MEL commands in the Script Editor.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try using [bakeSimulation](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/Commands/bakeSimulation.html) to convert the sim to ordinary vertex animations. You can then advance time to the desired time and export your OBJ that way.

This will disable the simulation once executed - it's good for getting the results but not editing them.

Comment: Yup.. Sounds much more solid than playing through and exporting. +1!

Comment: At the end of bakeSimulation, the scene comes back to the initial position  ! I cannot come back to the specific frame neither so I think the conversion from sim to animation fails :(

Comment: Maybe my code can give you more ideas: http://pastebin.com/8Mc1BifT . Thanks in advance !

Comment: I don't have access to maya right now, but you should be able to bake the range from your initial setup frame to the settling frame and then advance the frame to that time using `cmds.currentTime`

Comment: currentTime does not change much ... The frame is put to the indicated currentTime but the scene is unchanged :(

Comment: Does this work in Maya gui mode? Also try saving the output as an ma file and see if the simulation is indeed baked.

Comment: In old fashioned maya dynamics this should work, but perhaps nCloth expects an actual sim run?